# Rails nested routes wrong id

Tags: ruby-on-rails

At the moment I have a nested routes associated between my map and rows where a row `has_many` rows.

```
resources :maps do
  resources :rows
end
```

While looking in my rake routes:

```
edit_map_row GET    /maps/:map_id/rows/:id/edit(.:format) rows#edit
```

This is messing some things up, because if I look at the url while editing a row, it gives me this url.

```
http://localhost:3000/maps/11/rows/1/edit
```

The map_id is not 11; it is actually 1 and vice-versa. How can I change this in my routes so instead of the map_id being 11 is it 1 and the row_id is actually 11?

The route should look like this:

`edit_map_row GET    /maps/:id/rows/:row_id/edit(.:format) rows#edit`

Here are the set methods in my controllers if that helps.

**Maps controller**

```
private
    def set_row
      @row = Row.find(params[:id])
    end
```

**Rows Controller**

```
private
    def set_map
      @map = Map.find(params[:id])
    end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your routing is correct. The last controller id in your routes is always named `id` and all preceding show the controller name before the `id`.

Your rake routes seem correct then.

There is a problem in one of your private method though:

in maps controller:

```
private
    def set_row
      @row = Row.find(params[:id])
    end
```

You cannot have any row param here as your map resources is above your row resources. The route leading to any action of the map controller will never show any row.

In the row controller, your private method is wrong too, this time both map param and row param are avilable but as maps is preceding rows, you should be calling like:

```
private
    def set_map
      @map = Map.find(params[:map_id])
    end
```

My question is : do you have any error triggered at the moment ? And also make sure that when you pass a nested path into a `link_to` tag like `edit_map_row` that you pass the right ids in the brackets :

```
edit_map_row_path(map_id, row_id)
```

map_id and row_idd being what their name suggest butthat you can access from a variable like @map.id etc...

Answer (score 0):

You haven't really shared any context to indicate you're doing anything complex that warrants fighting against the rails convention.

The nested routes given to you are by convention, and the params names are by design (`:map_id` for the map, and `:id` for the row). In your current code, you're trying to `set_map` in the `RowsController` using the `:id` param, when ostensibly it's an id that should belong to a row, the object you'd like to work with at that route.

In your `MapsController` I don't know why you would need to use `set_row` (if you are calling it somewhere, please share). You can always find a map's rows by calling `@map.rows`

Your maps routes hitting the maps controller should have an `:id` param, which would then belong to a map's id. You probably want to have it like this:

**app/controllers/maps_controller.rb**

```
private
  set_map
    @map ||= Map.find(params[:id])
  end
```

For your rows controller, as you see, it expects a param called `:map_id`, and then the `:id` param would belong to a row.

You would then have something like this:

**app/controllers/rows_controller.rb**

```
 private
   def set_map
     @map ||= Map.find(params[:map_id])
   end

   def set_row
     @row ||= Row.find(params[:id])
   end
```

You could of course skip the `set_map` and find the map elsewhere with `row.map`.